# How to run a java program in cmd with arguments

Tags: java, cmd, javac

This is a beginner question. I am trying to run a java program from cmd with arguments. 
This is my class:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("This is a test");
        System.out.println(args.length);
    }
}
```

I can run it without arguments successfully. How can I put for example 5 and 6 as arguments in my program?

All the other answers I found where just to run the program. I already know how to do that. I was not able to find how to run the program using arguments.

Comment: check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: All the other answers I found where just to run the program. I know how to do that. I was not able to find how to run the program with arguments @jay

Comment: you just write them after

Comment: How do you run your program? In a command prompt or using an IDE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
java Test arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

or

```
java Test "arg1 arg2 arg3" ...
```

More details here [Command-Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)