# Exception in thread "main" :0

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Windchill {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        double t=Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double v=Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double w=35.74+0.6215*t+(0.4275*t-35.75)*Math.pow(v, 0.16);
        System.out.println("Windchill =" + w);
        }
        
    }
```

**Keep getting this error and unsure why can someone help:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Windchill.main(Windchill.java:5)
```

Comment: Looks like there is no argument passed to your `main`... `args` seems to be empty.

Comment: Indeed. args is empty, hence this error.

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're trying to get a value from an empty `String[]`.

On this line

```
double t = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
```

You try to get `args[0]` but are you giving any `args` when you run the program? [Check this link to see how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490628/how-to-run-a-java-program-in-cmd-with-arguments)

If you're not, you're trying to get 1 item from an array with `size = 0` which is more than it has, hence `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`